# URLs which have not www, not work

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've changed my routing configuration to support some kinds of URLs, But none of them not work without `www` and show this error.

> The resource cannot be found.

I can't found what's the problem here!

Routing:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "User",
                url: "User/{lang}/{pageId}/{seo}/{parameters}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Layout", action = "UserDashboardLayout", lang = "fa", pageId = 24, seo = "", parameters = "" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Module",
                "ModuleCode/{controller}/{action}",
                new { controller = "controller", action = "action", parameters = "" },
                new string[] { "Shoniz.Website.Controllers.Module" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "UserDashboard",
                url: "{lang}/{pageId}/{seo}/{parameters}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Layout", action = "MainLayout", lang = "en", pageId = 1, parameters = UrlParameter.Optional}
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}"
                ,
                defaults: new { controller = "Layout", action = "MainLayout", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "MainPage",
                url: "{lang}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Layout", action = "MainLayout", lang = "fa", pageId = 1, parameters = UrlParameter.Optional, seo = "Shoniz-Chocolate" }
                );

        }
    }
```

Comment: Does www.servername work for the main (default) route? If not you should check your DNS entries to ensure there is a www record for that host...

Comment: yes . when I use www it works for any URL

Comment: Well... not any URL, or you wouldn't have this problem....

Comment: I don't think your routing config has any effect on this, because it only deals with the part after the host

Comment: my website is this : www.shoniz.com. I don't know what's the problem here. I never face such problem

Comment: You should check DNS and WebServer configuration, it's not MVC question

Comment: @teovankot but other websites on host work correctly and have not problem and my site problems began when I changed my codes

Comment: I bet your request doesn't get to your changed MVC code. Check DNS and webserver that's what i suggest you to do

Comment: The first thing that you can do is cmd `nslookup www.yoursite.com` and `nslookup yoursite.com` are answers the same?